# Why this dangling pointer shows the same memory address even after freeing the memory?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Why the dangling pointer in the following program shows the same memory address even after freeing the memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int a = 1;

int *ptr_a = (int*)malloc((sizeof(int)));

ptr_a = &a;

printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", ptr_a);

free(ptr_a); // A dangling pointer

printf("The address of 'a' is %p", ptr_a);

return 0;
}
```

I tried everything but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Pointers hold an address. That address doesn't change just because what's there is no longer available. Why do you expect this to be different?

Comment: 1) Freeing memory does not change the value of the pointer that points to it, and 2) you are not freeing the memory you allocated but instead you are trying to free the address of a stack variable, which is bad news.

Comment: Oh, right, there's undefined behaviour in there too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Think about this: In C arguments are passed by value to a function. `free` is a function. How would it even be possible for `free` to change the address that is stored in a variable that is not visible to the function at all? Already from the fact that you call it `free(ptr)` and not `free(&ptr);` tells you that the value of `ptr` cannot be changed by the function.

Answer (score 1):

The code first allocates memory by calling `malloc`, and stores the returned address in `ptr_a`.  It then assigns the address of the local variable `a` to `ptr_a`.  At this point, the address of the memory returned by `malloc` is lost, resulting in a permanent memory leak.

It then passes `ptr_a`, i.e. the address of `a`, to `free`.  This is undefined behavior.  You may only pass pointers obtained by `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, etc. to `free`.

The pointer stored in `ptr_a` isn't changed by the call to `free`, so it prints the same address (unless something goes horribly wrong due to the undefined behavior caused by the bad call to `free`).